# Retrieve limited set of fields in response of Jira's REST API query

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm querying Jira's REST API in search of issues with this GET Request:

```
https://domain/jirainstance/rest/api/2/search/?jql=Sprint=Sprint34
```

This retrieves a JSON with the whole set of issues' fields. I would like to get the JSON with only the status and summary fields of the issue.

What's the way to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to use is: `fields=field1,field2`

In the example provided in the question it would be this way:

```
https://domain/jirainstance/rest/api/2/search/?jql=Sprint=Sprint34&fields=status,summary
```

This will produce a JSON response like this one:

```
{
"expand": "schema,names",
"startAt": 0,
"maxResults": 10,
"total": 159,
"issues": [
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "1015",
        "self": "https://domain/jirainstance/rest/api/2/issue/1015",
        "key": "KEYPRY-96",
        "fields": {
            "summary": "build the code",
            "status": {
                "self": "https://domain/jirainstance/rest/api/2/status/5",
                "description": "The code was built.",
                "iconUrl": "https://domain/jirainstance/images/icons/statuses/resolved.png",
                "name": "Resolved",
                "id": "5",
                "statusCategory": {
                    "self": "https://domain/jirainstance/rest/api/2/statuscategory/3",
                    "id": 3,
                    "key": "done",
                    "colorName": "green",
                    "name": "Done"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to retrieve only subfield? For example status.name. I've been searching around the docs but haven't found it

Comment: Not sure and I can't test because I'm not on that project anymore (I don't have access to the code I used). Try it anyway to see if it works.